# What is the reason for using async functions with REST?

Tags: javascript, rest, express

I am making a RESTful API with the express.js router. So, I have the following code (sorry if it's bad, I am learning):

```
router.route('/')
    .get(async (req, res) => {
        try {
            return await User.find(users => res.json(users))
        } catch(err) {
            return res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err)
        }
    })
```

Is there a reason for having async functions in this case, or could I get by just by using something like:

```
router.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        User.find((err, users) => {
            if(err){
                res.send(err)
            }
            else {
                res.send(users)
            }
        })
```

Comment: `async`/`await` is syntactic sugar over promises. They're identical in the end, but `async`/`await` is arguably easier to read in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `async` function lets you use `await` when consuming promises, which makes it possible to write the logic of your code using familiar flow control constructs rather than writing everything in callbacks.

**But**, since Express doesn't do anything with the promise you return, it's important to wrap **everything** in your callback in a `try`/`catch` (as shown in your question). Otherwise, an error / promise rejection in your code will result in an unhandled promise rejection.

You might look at [Koa](https://koajs.com/), from the same folks who did Express, which is built to work with promises.

Answer (score 2):

For a single `await`, then probably there's no difference for the two forms. However, the things get harder (to read) when you must deal with two or more asynchronous functions. In such cases, I'd strongly recommend the `async`/`await` pattern than the callback's one.